# Get elements from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an collections. Let's take one element from collection:

```
{
    "messages" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5503044be4b0e3d1aed29d15"),
        "body" : "Hello YOU!",
        "subject" : "sth"
     }
}
```

and now the tricky part. How to get elements from collection without wrapper. Like below:

```
{    
  "_id" : ObjectId("5503044be4b0e3d1aed29d15"),
  "body" : "Hello YOU!",
  "subject" : "sth"
}
```

Comment: @Michael The answer wasn't compleate. But I just voted up.

Comment: What else is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple you can use [**$project**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to add or reset a field within the document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$messages._id",
            "body": "$messages.body", 
            "subject": "$messages.subject"
         } 
     }
])
```